# How do I install plc-emu?

Tags: 10.10, installation

I have downloaded the tar.gz file for Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit from http://plcemu.sourceforge.net/ but I don't know how to install this.

Does anyone know how to install plc-emu from the .tar.zip?

Tried but i cant install the software...it gives error

```
melwin@Firefly:~/Desktop/plcemu-14a$ sudo make
[sudo] password for melwin: 
Makefile:25: warning: overriding commands for target `hardware.o'
Makefile:23: warning: ignoring old commands for target `hardware.o'
cc -O -g -c  plcemu.c
In file included from plclib.h:1,
                 from plcemu.c:1:
plcemu.h:6: fatal error: asm/io.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [plcemu.o] Error 1
```

Comment: You should uncompress and compile it. Use make. If there is any particular problem ask about it. Two details, before the flak starts: I know that this is not an answer, but he is asking for a tool to emulate plc programming, if he is ever going to use it he will need to know the basic of C programming, starting by compiling.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this writeup](http://www.instructables.com/id/A-Simple-Introduction-to-Transistors-and-PWM-Puls/step2/Programming-for-the-Parallel-Port/), the source code you are trying to compile is outdated and needs to include `sys/io.h` (from [libc6-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/libc6-dev), a dependency of [build-essential](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/build-essential)) instead of `asm/io.h`. [This forum post](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showpost.php?p=1285623) agrees.

If you're lucky, you might be able to simply modify `plcemu.h` with this change. However, if this results in more severe compilation errors, the problem is likely to be well outside the scope of Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: you are correct...is there any other way to install plcemu? or any other softwares like this.